# WPF styling . Have no idea how to do it

Tags: wpf, triggers, imagebutton, styling

I am trying to make an image button in WPF based on the following article

[Custom button template in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734825/custom-button-template-in-wpf/2735193#2735193)

The problem with this is that I have No Idea how to make the image to become grayscale when disabling the button. So I am loading two images, But I can not load a second images into ButtonProperties.
So my idea was to load an rgb and greyscale image, and as I disable the button one image is hidden and another shown, and vice versa. and also the text to get greyed out. As I think, this coulde be done very nicely with triggers.

Here is my code:

a) style

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="20"
               Name="imgEnabled"
               Source="{Binding Path=(ib:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></Image>
        <Image Width="20"
               Name="imgDisabled"
               Source="{Binding Path=(ib:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></Image>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></ContentPresenter>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

b) code:

```
public class ButtonProperties:DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Image", 
                                    typeof(ImageSource), 
                                    typeof(ButtonProperties), 
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));



    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
}
```

3) control:

```
<ItemsControl Name="icImageButtons"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button ToolTip="{Binding Tip}"
              ib:ButtonProperties.Image="{Binding EnabledSource}"
              Content="{Binding Text}"
              Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" />
    </DataTemplate>

  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Any suggestions or ideas. I am just trying to get the effect when I disable the ImageButton, The image gets greyedOut as well as the text.

Suggestions?

Comment: It shouldn't be so complicated. Just add Image as button's content and change it's source to different image based on IsEnabled property. Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2831359/1456174) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7796700/1456174)

Comment: The problem is also that I can not load another (different) image. As I try to copy the  source as another Property, I can not get it to build. Have no Idea where the GetImage and SetImage methods come from. I can not find any reference to it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22227/Grayscale-Button-Image-when-Disabled seems like what your looking for. Also the comments on the article gives a link to a `ShaderEffect` example to produce the same output

Comment: Both commenters' links provide good solutions to the problem. If you really wanted to match the style of the answer I gave in the question you linked, you'd need two attached properties (i.e. `ImageEnabled` and `ImageDisabled`) to get the two different sources, as well as a couple of Relative bindings to the button's `IsEnabled` property. It'd be pretty ugly. Go with a `ShaderEffect` if you can.

Comment: This  codeproject article looks amazing. Since I am still learning WPF, I have actually no Idea how to make it bindable. I tried to merge the code I provided with the one from the project, but failed miserably. Any Help please? this is driving me nuts.